# httplib.HTTPConnection in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, httplib

I use `httplib.HTTPConnection` within my app. Do I really need to provide `host` parameter in `httplib.HTTPConnection` constructor? If so, why? (I mean, I know that it's a mandatory parameter, but I wonder if I could specify `None` or empty string) And is there any global constant in Google AppEngine and in development server which I can use within my app in order to omit explicitly defined host.

Comment: As far as I understand I have to specify host name (for this parameter) of the current server where my application is hosted right now (please, correct me if I'm wrong). When I need to make a request I use `HTTPConnection.request()` method and it requires to specify URL explicitly which will be used.

Comment: Why use httplib at all? If you're working on App Engine, urlfetch is a better choice, and httplib is just a thin layer on top of it.

Comment: @Nick, yes you are right. I was working with SimpleOAuthClient that was used in Python's oauth module examples when I asked this question. And httplib was used there. After I sorted this example out, I refactored code in order to use urlfetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave it out of the constructor, how will the other methods know where to send their messages?

The address/name of the server you're connecting to is the parameter for the HTTPConnection, the URI on that server is what goes into request.

From the python documentation (which is the basis for AppEngine)

```
h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection(host[, port[, strict[, timeout[, source_address]]]])
h1.request(method, url[, body[, headers]])
```

[edit]

Remember, it may not always be you who is responsible for this code.  Also, why complicate things by including so much more information in the URI when you're (for example) making calls to numerous URI's on the same website?

[/edit]

Comment: Just help me clearly understand what is the difference between `host` (in the constructor) and `url` (in the request method). Do I understand right that `host` is just a host name (e.g. `foo.com`) and `url` is the URL path (e.g. `/path/to/resource`)?

Comment: Believe me, I don't try to make you angry :), I just want to clarify this question. I don't think that it works exactly as you mentioned, because I've just verified and `httplib.HTTPConnection` works perfectly if I specify `None` instead of real `host` and use full URL (not only path) for `request`'s method `url` parameter. Now I'm confident that it absolutely doesn't matter which value you use for `host` parameter (at least in the context of using `request` method).

Comment: I don't doubt you, but would recommend the suggested/documented route for use in production.

Comment: @asm That's probably an oddity of how the httplib wrapper works in App Engine. In any other environment, I think failing to specify a hostname would cause an error.